# What is the grammatical term for a noun after a gerund/infinitive

Tags: noun-phrases, grammatical-roles, gerund-phrases, infinitive-constructions, nonfinite-clause-complementation

For instance, there are the sentences "Reading *books* is good" and "To be a hero is your duty."

Could I say that *books* and "hero" are  objects of the verbs *reading* and *To be*, and that together( verb and object) act as a noun, more specifically, as the subject of both sentences?

Comment: Intransitive verbs, including copular ones like *be*, don't have objects; sometimes they have certain kinds of nominal (NP) complements, though. It's the clause that's the subject; there are no "acting nouns" here. I've updated your question's tags in the hope that these will better draw answers.

Comment: Thanks for seeing my question, but about the clause being the subject, that is the reason to why they have to be in the gerund or infinitive form, right? And about the first sentence,  Could I say that "books" is the object of "reading" even though gerunds are verbs that act as a noun? Oh, and thanks for correcting me about the verb "to be" not having an object, instead, an NP.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why a verb's object or complement might somehow be 
 called something different when the verb is nonfinite compared to when it's finite.  That would be confusing.

Comment: Yes and no: "reading books" and "to be a hero" are the subjects of the sentences, and "books" is the object of "reading". But "hero" is not an object: "be" is always intransitive, so it's predicative complement. Note that the subjects are not nouns but clauses.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> Yes and no: "reading books" and "to be a hero" are the subjects of the sentences, and "books" is the object of "reading". But "hero" is not an object: "be" is always intransitive, so it's predicative complement. Note that the subjects are not nouns but clauses.